# How to remove "read" notifications?

Tags: github, notifications

Last week (I think), the `mark all as read` button vanished from my GitHub notification page, maybe for a few days.

It eventually came back. But now, `read` notifications just accumulate in a dedicated `read` drawer and there seem to be no way of getting rid of them...

[image: no <code>clear</code> button]

What's going on with GitHub notifications this month?
Where can I find information (and motivation) about these new features?
How do I clear these notifications?

Comment: Sadly, the accepted answer is no longer valid. "Mark all as read" is gone, and if you don't clear notifications from a repo before it is deleted, you can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Marking all notifications as read
>
> - in the upper-right corner of any page, click the bell
> - in the upper right corner of the page, click **Mark all as read**
>
> **https://help.github.com/articles/marking-notifications-as-read/**

To remove **Read** notifications you can unread them into **Unread** or:

- unwatch repositories
- leave teams
- lock conversations
- wait a few days until they vanish on themselves

More about notifications: **[https://github.blog/notifications/](https://github.blog/2017-07-18-managing-large-numbers-of-github-notifications/)**

GitHub changelog: **https://github.blog/changelog/**

Feedback links:

- **https://github.community/**
- **https://github.com/contact**
- **https://enterprise.github.com/contact**
- **https://enterprise.githubsupport.com/hc/en-us/requests/new**

Comment: Hm, I see all this. Do you mean that the only way of clearing this new `read` drawer is to unwatch/leave/lock?

Comment: @iago-lito as far as I know - yes

Comment: Well, okay.. I'm curious too see how far this number of `read` notifications will go up before we get a way to archive them or get rid of them :P Thank you for the changelog and the feedback links :)

Comment: Ah, interestingly, the number seems to lower down day after day.. maybe they have some limited lifetime, yet undocumented now? :) Does this deserve an edit or another answer?

Comment: @iago-lito https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers